# Jquery Ajax with Leaflet and MarkerCluster Errors out

Tags: jquery, leaflet, markerclusterer

I have an application where I am loading markers dynamically by looping through a dataset.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var plateNo = data[i].PLATE_NUMBER;
                var permitNo = data[i].PERMITINFOID;
                var popup = '<h5>EPS</h5>' + 'Plate:' + plateNo + '<br/>' +
                    ' Permit: <a class=\'link\'  href=' + url + '>' + permitNo + '</a>' + 
                    '<p style=\"color:blue\">' + '' + '<a class=\'link\'  href=' + url + '>' + 
                    'Import' + '</a>' + '<br/>' + '<a class=\'link\'  href=' + url + '>' + 
                    'Duplicate' + '</a>' + '<br/>' + '<a class=\'link\'  href=' + url + '>' + 
                    'Removed' + '</a>' + '<br/>' + '</p>';

                var m = L.marker([data[i].REF_LATITUDE, data[i].REF_LONGITUDE], { icon: epsiconR, draggable: 'true' })
                                    .bindPopup(popup);
                markerClusters.addLayer(m);

                }
                map.addLayer(markerClusters);
            map.invalidateSize(false);
```

I am attaching an event handler to each of the items with class 'link' like this:

```
  map.on('popupopen', function () {
            $('.link').click(function (e) {
                createDialog();
            });
        });
```

I am ajax loading a different page in the createDialog method like this:

```
 function createDialog() {
             $("#testPara").slideToggle("slow");
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/home/UpdateInventory',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#testPara').html(data);
            }
        });
```

}

The markers cluster fine and clicking on the popups ajax loads the div just fine. However once the Ajax load is done if I try to zoom in or out of the map or drag the map around I get an error Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Map simply freezes after that. I have been stuck on this for an entire day and would greatly appreciate any help or input.

This fiddle shows the issue, when you click on a link the console shows error

http://jsfiddle.net/pk9vbvs4/

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't reproduce the behavior you're describing. The error I see is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null` (occurring when the popup link is clicked), and there is no problem dragging or zooming afterward. The error in the fiddle appears to be due to the AJAX url pointing to `/`, i.e. the jsfiddle page itself, while the `Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined` error appears to be related to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are trying to load a page which has scripts that collide with the current page scripts (and possibly document id's as well). At least in your jsFiddle, you try to load the very same page (using `url: '/'`), which breaks all the JavaScript.

All scripts are loaded twice, and initialization code is run again on variables that are not re-initialized, so weird things happen.

Demo of loading something without any script inside: http://jsfiddle.net/pk9vbvs4/1/ Everything still runs fine.

Since we do not have any detail about the target page, I cannot tell for sure this is the root cause for your issue.

Comment: You are correct. This is a non issue once I looked through your fiddle. Thank you for taking the time and effort...